# Working with Time Slider and Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, data-driven-pages, dynamic, spatio-temporal-data

I have parcel polygon data from 1900 to 2000.  Using the Time Slider tool I can animate the parcel map. I would like to parcel attribute information like grantor name as the map is populated over time. I tried data driven pages but could not get the time slider tool and the dynamic text data drven page name to sync.

Can this be done?

Comment: So, are you saying you would like to populate a text element with the grantor name(s) over time? What is your goal for this project? An animated parcel map over time doesn't seem to mix well with separate pages for each parcel (which is what Data Driven Pages would get you).

Comment: We would like to depict the history of land acquisition and disposal over time.  Captions that give a brief comment as the parcels come and go.